# AutoCAD 図形を選択するVBAマクロについて

Tags: vba, autocad

お世話になっております。
AutoCADのVBAの開発についての質問です。
図面内の全ての図形を探索して「A」という名前のブロックを検索し、その属性情報を変更するマクロを作成しています。

```
For Each objEntity In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
    If objEntity.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
        Set objEntity2 = objEntity
        If InStr(objEntity2.Name, "A") > 0 Then
           objEntity3 = objEntity2.GetAttributes()
           objEntity3(0).TextString = Left(objEntity3(0).TextString, 10)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

この方法だと図形が数千個存在する場合、10秒程かかります。
高速に検索できる方法がありましたらご教授ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectionSetのフィルター機能を使用してみてください。